# Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Im currently developing the frontend part of a crud application. I was implementing lazy pagination when I got this error

> Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

I have already looked into planty of questions with the same error, but I didn't find any solutions

Obs: already tried using the pipe `| keyvalue`, didnt work

Here is a part of the **object I'm passing to the pagination** = cidades:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "nome": "Florianópolis",
        "qtdHabitantes": null,
        "estado": "SC"
    },
    ...
]
```

Here's the **service where i do the request**:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Pageable } from '../pageable';
import { RequestUtil } from '../request-util';
import { Cidade } from './cidade';
import { CidadeFiltro } from './cidadeFiltro';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CidadeService {

  apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  cidadesUrl = environment.slashApi + '/cidades';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  listar(filtro: CidadeFiltro, pageable: Pageable): Observable<any>{
    const options = RequestUtil.buildOptions(Object.assign(filtro, pageable));
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.cidadesUrl}`, options);
  }
  ...
```

**My component.ts:**

```js
export class CidadesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @ViewChild('grid') grid: any;

  cidades: any[] = [];

  estado = new Estado();

  estados = [];

  estadoSelected:any = '';

  filtro = new CidadeFiltro();
  pageable = new Pageable();

  totalRegistros = 0;

  @BlockUI('lista-cidades') blockUI!: NgBlockUI;

  constructor(private cidadeService:CidadeService, private messageService: MessageService ) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.cidades = this.cidades
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listar();
    this.estados = this.estado.estados;
  }

  listar(pagina:number = 0){
    this.blockUI.start();
    this.filtro.estado = this.estadoSelected.name;
    this.pageable.page = pagina;
    this.cidadeService.listar(this.filtro, this.pageable).pipe(finalize(() => this.blockUI.stop())).subscribe(data => {
      this.totalRegistros = data.totalElements;
      this.cidades = data.content;
    }),
    retry(3),
    catchError(error => {
      console.log('Não foi possível listar as cidades');
      return of(0);
    });
  }
```

And last my **component.html**

```html
<div *blockUI="'lista-cidades'">
  <p-table [value]="cidades" #grid
    [lazy]="true" [totalRecords]="registros" (onLazyLoad)="aoMudarPagina($event)"
  [paginator]="true" [rows]="size" responsiveLayout="scroll">

    <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
      <tr><td>Nenhuma cidade encontrada</td></tr>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Habitantes</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-cidade>
        <tr>
            <td>{{cidade.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{cidade.qtdHabitantes | number}}</td>
            <td>{{cidade.estado}}</td>
            <td class="acoes">
              <button pButton icon="pi pi-pencil" pTooltip="Editar" tooltipPosition="top" [routerLink]="['/cidades', cidade.id]"></button>
              <button pButton class="p-button-danger" icon="pi pi-trash"  pTooltip="Excluir" tooltipPosition="top"
              (click)="deletar(cidade)"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

error log:

```
ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.mjs:27502)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.mjs:3170)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2552)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2511)
    at executeCheckHooks (core.mjs:2443)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9493)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10609)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9508)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280)
```

Can someone help me?

***UPDATE***
I have thinked about implementing this code in the `listar()` method:

```
listar(pagina:number = 0){
    this.blockUI.start();
    this.filtro.estado = this.estadoSelected.name;
    this.pageable.page = pagina;
    this.cidadeService.listar(this.filtro, this.pageable).pipe(finalize(() => this.blockUI.stop())).subscribe(data => {
      this.totalRegistros = data.totalElements;
      this.cidades.push(data.content);
      this.cidades = this.cidades[0];
      console.log(this.cidades)
    })
```

but then i get the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

And my list becomes empty

Comment: Hello @tabletigr! what's `p-table` is it a library or another component? I'm thinking that you might be binding the wrong property to a `*ngfor` or something like

Comment: Hi @rmjoia, p-table is a component from primeng. And no, im not biding the wrong property to the for loop, its actually supposed to be cidades, but i think im supposed to get the value as an array or something like that

Comment: put complete error log and what is there in cidades?

Comment: @tabletigr I saw it was cidades, was just wondering if the component was doing something else. if you could put something on stackblitz or something that people can look at might be easier to help, not sure if it's possible though.

Comment: Hi @AakashGarg, edited the question, the object i showed on the question is what is inside of cidades

Comment: @rmjoia i dont know if i can upload since the frontend part is too big, tried once and didnt work. But i think the code I already shared here is probably enough

Comment: if you log out in the listar subscription `data.content` what does it output?

Comment: in ngonchanges try :- this.cidades = this.cidades ?? [];

Comment: @rmjoia you mean a `console.log(data.content)`? If so, it output the object that i showed

Comment: @AakashGarg i have just implemented, but the error keeps showing up, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @tabletigr I think that we suspect that there's something being assigned to cidades which is not an array. I would stay away as much as possible of type any to avoid this. By using any, you opt out of type safety and you're just doing javascript.

Comment: @rmjoia so do you suggest i use a class to do so?

Comment: something in the service like `return this.http.get<Cidades[]>` would ensure that if something else is retrieved you get a warning or null. Also, use ` cidades: Cidades[] = [];` instead, and you might see where the problem is, when something else is assigned, I think @AakashGarg suspects the ngchanges is making something else

Comment: Wow @rmjoia, just by adding `cidades: Cidade[] =[]` it solved the problem!! If you could post an answer and up vote the question so other people can see it, because no question i enter talking about this error talked about the type of the array.

Comment: @tabletigr done, but, I don't think is a good answer since I don't know exactly what the problem is, maybe the any type is doing something else, while having the type specified helps the compiler/transpiler to figure out what is your intention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that is popping up to me is that you're using the any type.

Doing something in the service like return this.http.get<Cidades[]> would ensure that the response will be parsed to an array of Cidades and might let you know if something goes wrong there. (I can't remember exactly if it throws if it can't)

Take a look at [Requesting a typed response](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response)

Also, use `cidades: Cidades[] = [];` instead, and you might see where the problem is, when something else is assigned.

Avoid as much as possible to use the type `any` or you'll loose all the type safety and strange things might happen.

For instance, if something else that isn't Cidades[] is assigned to this.cidades the compiler will complain in design time and you can see what's going on.

Since I didn't create a project with your code I don't know exactly what the error is.

Comment: no prob. I use the any type only on tests where I don't care much about type-safety and even then, only if I can't come up with a type.

Answer (score 0):

My code was like this when I had this problem:

```js
public join: IReservation[] |any; 

loadreserve(): void {
    this.reserve.list().subscribe((daya) => {
        this.dispo = daya; 
        for (let ter of this.dispo) {
            let toto : number|any = ter.terrain?.nbrJoueurs; 
            let tat: number|any = ter.nbrjoueur; 
            this.comp = toto - tat;
            if (this.comp >= this.numberofJoin) {
                this.join = ter;
                console.log(this.join);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem: During my for loop, I returned an object to display it, but I needed an array of objects, so I made this modification:

```js
loadreserve(): void {
    this.join = [];
    this.reserve.list().subscribe((daya) => {
        this.dispo = daya; 
        for (let ter of this.dispo) {
            let toto : number|any = ter.terrain?.nbrJoueurs; 
            let tat: number|any = ter.nbrjoueur; 
            this.comp = toto - tat;
            if (this.comp >= this.numberofJoin) {
                this.join.push(ter);
                console.log(this.join);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a .Net Core API with an Angular front-end. My issue was caused by calling an external API which was returning HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. The unhandled error was then showing as an NG0900 in the console. The root cause ended up being that data migrations were not applied to the external API.